# Single Mono file into left channel only 5.1 channel file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to set up a Halloween display with a 6 talking props. Only one prop will be speaking at a time with a speaker placed behind the prop.  I am currently using AWS's Polly to generate mono channel MP3s to play.

How do I use FFMPEG to convert my single mono file into a file with 6 channels but the input is only playing on one of the channels? The goal is make the sound come from only one Halloween prop at a time.

I have read the documentation here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation but not sure how to apply it to my situation.

Comment: "the input is only playing on one of the channels"? You mean one at a time, each speaker in some sort of rotation? Make 6 mono channels, one for each prop/speaker. Combine to make 5.1 - see the '6 × mono → 5.1' section.

Comment: I would need to add "silence' to the other channels somehow as I dont have 6 files.  I have audio files where the audio is speech like "Hi, I am talking prop number 3". I would like to play that clip just on the speaker behind that particular prop.

Comment: To play to 6 outputs you need 6 channels, no matter how you dice it. You could split it up in something like Audacity [which can also then export to 5.1], but you're going to need 6 channels. You can pan mono to 6 outputs in a full-blown DAW [expensive, idk of a free one]… but the resulting saved file is still going to have 6 individual channels, wrapped as 5.1.

Comment: Not the best solution... You may try the "Combine 6 mono inputs into one 5.1" example, with 1 mono input and 5 anullsrc inputs. Replace `-f lavfi -i sine=frequency=100` with your mono audio file.

Comment: Example: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=100 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=44100 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=44100 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=44100 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=44100 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=44100 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a]join=inputs=6:channel_layout=5.1:map=0.0-FL|1.0-FR|2.0-FC|3.0-LFE|4.0-BL|5.0-BR" -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 6 -t 10 six_ch_fl_only.mp4`

Comment: Yes, i went with this but split up a little to make it a little easier to read... here is what i have in a bash file

seconds=$(ffprobe -i $1 -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0")
echo $seconds
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=44100:cl=mono -t $seconds -q:a 9 -acodec libmp3lame slient.mp3
ffmpeg -i slient.mp3 -i $1 -i slient.mp3 -i slient.mp3 -i slient.mp3 -i slient.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a]join=inputs=6:channel_layout=5.1[a]" -map "[a]" output.mp3

Comment: @Rotem please answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I am going to pass... I don't think my solution is good enough. I also don't want to use your `seconds=$(ffprobe -i $1 -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0")` solution. Fill free to post an answer to your question.